# Does Puppeteer's waitForSelector wait for child elements to load before resolving?

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors, jestjs, puppeteer

Let's say I have an element with the class name of `.parent-element` with three children elements.

When I call `await page.waitForSelector('.parent-element');` Does Puppeteer wait for all of the children elements to render before resolving?

Or does Puppeteer resolve as soon as the opening tag for the parent element appear in the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

Puppeteer will not wait for the children to render when you `await page.waitForSelector('.parent-element');`.

This is because Puppeteer simly cannot know if the node should have any children or not.

Answer (score -1):

Chrome doesn't really have a concept of an "unclosed tag" - if you do:

```js
document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = '<div>Unclosed';
console.log(document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML)
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"/>
```

It immediately is closed by virtue of how Chrome parses things. So, it depends on what you mean by "rendered", but if you are wondering if you do:

```
document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = '<div>/*a lot of stuff*/<img/></div>';
```

if the `img` *tag* will "be there" once the `wrapper` selector exists, then yes.

If you are wondering whether the image will have *loaded* then not necessarily.

Comment: Encourage the question poster to edit his question, he clearly meant to ask if Puppeteer's waitForSelector function resolves when a node conforming to the selector appears, even though it doesn't have children.